# Ajax custom templating engine

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dynamic, template-engine

I have a project that is simulating an exam system, except that it needs to display custom questions. I have a question regarding implementing this dynamic question section.

Here is what I have so far:

`{q::lecture1::2::all}`

I am pulling all the questions into JS using AJAX and what I want to do is find everything between {} and render questions. For the example above, it should do the following:

find {q::lecture1::2::all}

parse based off of ::, so that you have [q][lecture1][2][all]

then on the [2] index pull questions from the AJAX question list, and render

I have the parsing/exploding step done, but I can't figure out how find all of the {} on a page, and then pull in the question list and render just x questions (based off of that third index)

Background: it has to be custom code, no external templating engines are allowed.

Thank you so much for the help.

EDIT: the first step is done as well.

Comment: So, you're embedding `{q::lecture1::2::all}` in your HTML? Why not instead have legit HTML elements with special IDs? You could id them like `id="q_lecture1_2_all"` and easily find them using jQuery.

Comment: Because that is the format that is wanting to be used to tag all of the question just like in underscore or mustache.

Comment: Embedding non-HTML in HTML makes it really hard to find stuff using the DOM.

Comment: This is a system that I need to make for non programmers just to load their questions.

Comment: I can find the elements just find just trying to now insert the question template and Ajax in the information for each question.

Comment: all tags inside the body can receive the markup ?

Comment: to do the second step, you can use `var params = markup.split("::")`

Comment: Thank you. Already have that step done. Only the third step is what I need help on.

Comment: send to server the array with params, in server you return a HTML-Rendered with your questions or the questions list and put in html...